# Is it possible to conditionally change the font with a script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for something fairly simple. I used to do a little VB back then (ok, way back then) and I'm wondering if I can change the font-family and font-size with a script. I have two specific cases in mind. It would, in my mind, be a very simple OnEdit(e) functions like:

If Cell A1 = blank then Cell B1 = "change the font code"
and for another sheet
If Cell A1= blank then Cell A2 = "change the font code"

to be applied on the whole columns... I'm new at this, don't judge.
Thanks!

Comment: Go [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) search for "font"

Comment: A couple of screenshots (1 - what you have, 2 - what you want to have) wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to ensure that your question has 1) a [minimal, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which in turn contains 2) clearly defined inputs, and 3) clearly defined desired output.

For Google Sheet questions, please include example sheet (unless it's very atomic questions), in addition to parameters that define your input/output data. 

As is, your question is not clear at all in defining a problem to be solved. 

(And sure it's possible.)